# extracting links from a text

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract links from a text starting with "q=http"  and before "&amp" ie i want to get the text between these two and my output should be like

```
http://ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html
```

which stats from "http" and ends before "&amp"
What I tried is

```
        Pattern p =  Pattern.compile(".*?q=(http:.*?)&amp");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
        String pageid = "";
        if (m.find())
        {
             pageid = m.group(1);

        }         
                System.out.println(pageid);
```

**below is the content of my file text.html...**

```
 q=http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/supreme-court-execution-of-nithari-killer-surinder-koli/article6390120.ece&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CBQQpwI&amp;usg=AFQjCNFDcbVK87iUjDwI21jbIZUg0aU8gQ"><img class="th" height="100" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUUkUw1JxXWJQj2SCQr3XxoIcY5OpWLzDgHIqvLzDgmrfntT9nRi99Lvuuheh05L50VDbs-pY" width="100" border="1"><br></a><span class="_pJb _yhd">The Hindu</span></td><td valign="top"><div style="margin-top:5px"><a href="/url?q=http://ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CBYQqQIwAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFPPZfQCJQH3vFo1I9Avu-ug8EcSg">Noida&#39;s <b>Nithari killings</b>: SC stays execution of convict Surinder Koli for a week</a><div style="padding-top:2px"><cite>IBNLive</cite><span class="f"> - <span class="nobr">1 hour ago</span><span class="nobr"></span></span></div><div class="j" style="margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:4px"><span class="st">New Delhi: The Supreme Court has stayed the execution of Noida&#39;s <b>Nithari</b> <b>killings</b> convict Surinder Koli for one week. An official of the apex&nbsp;...</span></div></div><div style="margin-top:4px"><a href="/url?q=http://www.firstpost.com/india/sc-defers-nithari-killings-convict-surendra-kolis-hanging-week-1701475.html&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CBgQqQIwAQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNGsfNy0HC_rfyMfPSSpU66FmUydIw">SC defers <b>Nithari killings</b> convict Surendra Koli&#39;s hanging by a week</a><div style="padding-top:2px"><cite>Firstpost</cite><span class="f"> - <span class="nobr">1 hour ago</span><span class="nobr"></span></span></div></div><div style="margin-top:4px"><a href="/url?q=http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/nithari-killer-surinder-koli-to-be-hanged-on-sept-12-jail-authorities/article1-1260116.aspx&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CBoQqQIwAg&amp;usg=AFQjCNEjeDnCXSwCCWtXO87tIhj6athCCA"><b>Nithari</b> case: Surinder Koli to be hanged on Sept 12</a><div style="padding-top:2px"><cite>Hindustan Times</cite><span class="f"> - <span class="nobr">3 days ago</span><span class="nobr"></span></span></div></div></td></tr></table></div></li><li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CBwQFjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNGATKIaCWR1Hl-yqEqXcb1XnXKu9g">Noida serial <b>murders</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_<b>murders</b></cite><div class="_nBb">‎<div style="display:inline" onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CB0Q7B0wAw"><span class="_O0"></span></div><div style="display:none" class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1"><ul><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den-IN%26q%3Dcache:ITALXEhw0j8J:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders%252Bnithari%2Bkillings%2Bnews%26gbv%3D2%26%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CB8QIDAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNFx4v82ZSgfuIZHJmenK1Xv6jxYpw">Cached</a></li><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/search?hl=en-IN&amp;gbv=2&amp;q=related:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders+nithari+killings%09news&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCAQHzAD">Similar</a></li></ul></div></div></div><span class="st">The Noida serial <b>murders</b> (also <b>Nithari</b> serial <b>murders</b>, <b>Nithari</b> Kand) took ... The <br>
police then sealed the house and did not allow <b>news</b> media anywhere near the&nbsp;...</span><br><div class="osl">‎<a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders%23Events_leading_to_primary_investigation&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCIQ0gIoADAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNFoFLoEv_CGAkKNe2WFNpQdqTyRag">Events leading to primary ...</a> - ‎<a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders%23Primary_investigation&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCMQ0gIoATAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNFFSz2pBFdWoUAGkp2sZ_KpAmBoUg">Primary investigation</a> - ‎<a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders%23CBI_investigation&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCQQ0gIoAjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNHlovBCPUSSGlExpuZHJxtDHQUZ7A">CBI investigation</a> - ‎<a href="/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noida_serial_murders%23Victims&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCUQ0gIoAzAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNFgkfguy3vUxvh8JmS-ncgfIxOLNA">Victims</a></div></div></li><li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.ndtv.com/topic/nithari-killings&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCcQFjAE&amp;usg=AFQjCNESpfXGZ4DE-uVDo8LvQ42kHVU4Bg"><b>Nithari Killings</b>: Latest <b>News</b>, Photos, Videos on <b>Nithari</b> <b>...</b> - NDTV.com</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>www.ndtv.com/topic/<b>nithari</b>-<b>killings</b></cite><div class="_nBb">‎<div style="display:inline" onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CCgQ7B0wBA"><span class="_O0"></span></div><div style="display:none" class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1"><ul><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den-IN%26q%3Dcache:a6vXEobpypEJ:http://www.ndtv.com/topic/nithari-killings%252Bnithari%2Bkillings%2Bnews%26gbv%3D2%26%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCoQIDAE&amp;usg=AFQjCNGiRwJ84qtiMaU-6ag_SMMyugi2-g">Cached</a></li><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/search?hl=en-IN&amp;gbv=2&amp;q=related:www.ndtv.com/topic/nithari-killings+nithari+killings%09news&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CCsQHzAE">Similar</a></li></ul></div></div></div><span class="st">Find <b>Nithari Killings</b> Latest <b>News</b>, Videos &amp; Pictures on <b>Nithari Killings</b> and see <br>
latest updates, <b>news</b>, information from NDTV.COM. Explore more on <b>Nithari</b>&nbsp;...</span><br></div></li><li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/India/SC-stays-execution-of-Nithari-killer-Surinder-Koli/articleshow/41998225.cms&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CC0QFjAF&amp;usg=AFQjCNHAHTcrXEtqeYz_1KPmz-6AxK93RA">SC stays execution of <b>Nithari</b> killer Surinder Koli - The Times of India</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>timesofindia.indiatimes.com/India/SC...<b>Nithari</b>.../41998225.cms</cite><div class="_nBb">‎<div style="display:inline" onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CC4Q7B0wBQ"><span class="_O0"></span></div><div style="display:none" class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1"><ul><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den-IN%26q%3Dcache:OvKjSrI26NwJ:http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/India/SC-stays-execution-of-Nithari-killer-Surinder-Koli/articleshow/41998225.cms%252Bnithari%2Bkillings%2Bnews%26gbv%3D2%26%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=qTUNVOalHMe2uATE_YGQDw&amp;ved=0CDAQIDAF&amp;usg=AFQjCNHV4qIIoJ8sR79KTPOCIyUhWNwwCg">Cached</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookbehind to lookafter the string `q=http:` and lookahead to look before the string `&amp`

```
(?<=q=http:).*?(?=\\s*&amp)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/1)

```
String s = "q=http://ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html &amp 1 hour agoNoida's Nithari killings: SC stays execution of convict Surinder Koli for a weekIBNLive - 1 hour agoNew Delhi: The Supreme Court has stayed the execution of Noida's Nithari killings convict\n"
        + " Surinder Koli for one week.\n"
        + "q=http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/nithari-killer-surinder-koli-to-be-hanged-on-sept-12-jail-authorities/article1-1260116.aspx &amp\n";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=q=http:).*?(?=\\s*&amp)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
//ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html
//www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/nithari-killer-surinder-koli-to-be-hanged-on-sept-12-jail-authorities/article1-1260116.aspx
```

**OR**,

This would match only the links which are preceeded  by `q=` and starts with `http:`

```
String s = "q=http://ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html &amp 1 hour agoNoida's Nithari killings: SC stays execution of convict Surinder Koli for a weekIBNLive - 1 hour agoNew Delhi: The Supreme Court has stayed the execution of Noida's Nithari killings convict\n"
        + " Surinder Koli for one week.\n"
        + "q=http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/nithari-killer-surinder-koli-to-be-hanged-on-sept-12-jail-authorities/article1-1260116.aspx &amp\n";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=q=)http:.*?(?=\\s*&amp)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
http://ibnlive.in.com/news/noidas-nithari-killings-sc-stays-execution-of-convict-surinder-koli-for-a-week/497153-3-242.html
http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/nithari-killer-surinder-koli-to-be-hanged-on-sept-12-jail-authorities/article1-1260116.aspx
```

Comment: @chopu: missing double quote in: Pattern.compile("(?<=q=).*?(?=\\s*&amp)");

Comment: @AvinashRaj  your answer is also right .but it is giving me only one link not the entire set of links which satisfies the above rules..i don't know what went wrong

Comment: did you add multiline modifier?, `Pattern.compile("(?<=q=http:).*?(?=\\s*&amp)", Pattern.MULTILINE);`. See my answer it works for me.

Comment: still not working...just save my mentioned contents to a file as text.txt/html and pass the variable "content" inside Pattern class

Comment: does your input contains only 3 newline characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60805/discussion-between-chopu-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
q=(http(?>[^&]+|&(?!amp))*)
```

Then capture group1

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/jsXIIiM18N)

Comment: i want to chech those starting with q=http.   bcoz there are also other text other than links starting with same

Comment: your answer is also right Walid..but it is giving me only one link not the entire set of links which satisfies the above rules

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?q=(http:.*?)&amp
```

Try this.This gives all the matches.

See here.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/9

Comment: @chopu 14 matches are what i m getting.are there more?

Comment: that's right...but it can vary when i specify a different keyword

Comment: results may vary based on keywords @vks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60806/discussion-between-chopu-and-vks).